# Exponential form of $A\cos(kx-\omega t+\phi)$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I want to write the following in exponential form:
$$
\psi(x,t)=A\cos(kx-\omega t+\phi)
$$
Attempt:
\begin{align}
\psi(x,t)&=\Re\{A e^{i(kx-\omega t+\phi)}\}\\
&=
\Re\{A e^{i\phi} e^{i(kx-\omega t)}  \}\\
&=\Re\{A_0 e^{i(kx-\omega t)} \}
\end{align}
So $A_0=Ae^{i\phi}$, but is this a complex number?

In general we have $z=a+ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\theta}$.

Does it mean I actually have  $A_0=a_0+ib_0=\sqrt{a_0^2+b_0^2}e^{i\phi}=Ae^{i\phi}$? So $\sqrt{a_0^2+b_0^2}=A$?

Answer (score 0):

Use the exponential definition of the cosine:$$cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
So $$\psi(x,t)=A\frac{e^{i(kx-\omega t +\phi)}+e^{-i(kx-\omega t +\phi)}}{2}$$

Comment: I tried
$
\psi(x,t)=A\frac{e^{i(kx-\omega t +\phi)}+e^{-i(kx-\omega t +\phi)}}{2}=
A\frac{e^{i\phi}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}+e^{-i\phi}e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}}{2}=\\
=
\frac{Ae^{i\phi}}{2}\frac{e^{i(kx-\omega t)}}{2}+
\frac{Ae^{-i\phi}}{2}\frac{e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}}{2}
$. I'm stuck here, what is the next step?

Comment: Why do you need an additional step, your answer is already in exponential form, unless you want an answer in a specific form?